# Relative clause & "whose"

Tags: relative-clauses, subjects, objects

> 1. *That is the guy whose car is broken*.
> 2. *That is the guy whose car I rented*.

What is the function of "whose" in both of above sentences. Is it subject or object, or something else of the relative clause? Kindly elaborate function of each part of speech *those* plays in above both sentences.

Comment: In both cases, "whose" has "guy" as antecedent. Its function is that of determiner in the genitive noun phrase "guy's car".  In 1. the noun phrase is subject, and in 2 object.

Answer (score 1):

> "That is the guy whose car is broken" means: "He is the **owner** **of** the broken car."

"Whose" states that the object at the right of it belongs to the noun at the left of it.

> "I saw the man whose wife is my mother's friend" means: "The woman who is my mother's friend is the wife **of** the man I saw.